# how can I grant privileges to Linux user?

Tags: linux, debian, rhel

for Example I will make a user called username

I need to grant all root privileges to user username

Comment: That's probably not a good idea: I would look into the `sudo` package if i were you.

Comment: You shouldn't. You should provide [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) access to this user for specific programs that she might need to execute with root privileges.

Comment: yeah , but it's just for my own usage and it's a home server so I'm not afraid of that

Comment: I would *still* recommend that you use sudo.

Answer (score 1):

Think through this carefully, do this user really need access to everything root does? Because it is a security list. The approach I have taken is to only given the access needed to another user such as apache, for example for that is truly needed. I know it is easier to just give another user all access that root has but things can get sloppy pretty easily this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to grant all root privileges, why not not use username `root` in the first place?